# Using boost::mutex::scoped_lock inside const function

Tags: c++, constants, boost-mutex

This code won't compile:

```
    class MyClass
    {
        boost::mutex _mutex; 

        void foo() const
        {
          boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(_mutex);
         //critical section
        }
    }
```

But defining the function as non const will work fine.
Please, can someone explain why?
Thanks!

Comment: In critical section there there is peek into a data structure.

Comment: @imreal There may be another non-const function which does modify MyClass. The mutex protects simultaneous reading and writing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't lock a mutex inside a const-member function because this actually modifies the internal state of the mutex (`lock` is not itself a `const` function).

If you want to keep the function `const`, you'll have to declare the mutex as `mutable` which is a cv-qualifier that allows const functions to modify it, i.e.

```
//can now be locked (i.e. modified) by a const function
mutable boost::mutex _mutex;
```

Using `mutable` relax the `const` constraints on the member variable which is declared with this qualifier, that's a way to get around constness, so be careful not to abuse this. In this case, it seems reasonable because a mutex is an internal tool of your class, and does not participate in "logical constness" (as opposed to "bitwise constness").

Comment: You can declare it as `mutable`

Answer (score 3):

This code should compile

```
class MyClass
{
    mutable boost::mutex _mutex; 
    void foo() const
    {
       boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(_mutex);
       //critical section
    }
}
```

Comment: Please can you explain why it didn't work. Is locking the _mutex is 'modifing' it?

Comment: See the @Bas in het Veld comment, he explains the reasons :-).

Answer (score 1):

Raistmaj is right.

The reason is that a constant method guarantees it does not change its class instance. By declaring the mutex mutable, you make an exception for that variable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs because `boost::mutex::lock()`, which is called by the constructor of `boost::mutex::scoped_lock`, is **not** a `const` member function. Since the mutex is a member of `MyClass`, that means that `MyClass::_mutex::lock()` cannot be called from a non-`const` member function of `MyClass`.

The solution is to declare the mutex as a `mutable` member. This indicates to the compiler that `_mutex` may be modified, even in a `const` member function:

```
class MyClass
{
    mutable boost::mutex _mutex; 

    void foo() const
    {
      boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(_mutex);
     //critical section
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> > Please can you explain why it didn't work. Is locking the _mutex is 'modifing' it?

Precisely, the _mutex object will change it's internal state from say "unlocked" to "locked" state. So, you need the mutable keyword fora const-function to preserve logical constness of the function while allowing the mutex to be modifiable.